# Chained selectors in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, closest

I have a Rails form which has a number of tables.  One of the tables has an drop-down element of interest which can be accessed by its id like so:

```
$('#contract_contract_phases_attributes_0_ngl_price_term')
```

I am showing/hiding another element based on the value selected in it, which is no problem.  Trouble is: the table header row for the element has 'th' element which I need to show/hide with it.  I can get to the parent table element like so:

```
$('#contract_contract_phases_attributes_0_ngl_price_term').closest('table')
```

However, I am trying to target the header element (th) that needs to be hidden by giving it a class of 'price_term'.  So I am trying to further narrow down the closest element to this th element like so:

```
$('#contract_contract_phases_attributes_0_ngl_price_term').closest('table th.price_term')
```

However, this does not work.  Is there a way that I can target this header element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.closest()` only looks at the parent, grandparent, great-grandparent, etc. - only goes upwards in the DOM.

`.find()` only looks at children, grandchildren, etc. - it goes downwards through the DOM.

As such, you want to go up (`.closest()`) to the table, and down (`.find()`) to the th.price_term:

```
$('#contract_contract_phases_attributes_0_ngl_price_term')
    .closest('table')
    .find('th.price_term')
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
$('#contract_contract_phases_attributes_0_ngl_price_term').closest('table').find('th.price_term')
```

Comment: Hello Tracy,  Yes.  thanks this works.  It is the same as above.  I appreciate your time.